# Reducing the occurrence of taboo terms in LLM output

Tags: llm

What are some ways to reduce the occurrence of certain taboo or abusive terms in LLM responses? Assume I'm using Chat GPT, is there an established or empirically tested way to construct a preamble to avoid certain words or phrases?

Comment: You are the first person I've seen complain about this. Everyone else has issues with it being too politically-correct. What is your idea of "abusive?" You can always stipulate this request in the system prompt for ChatGPT (check the profile icon in the lower left corner).

Comment: We have certain esoteric phrases that should be avoided, but in my testing simply adding "don't say the following terms: " in the preamble seems to help but doesn't solve the issue all the time.

Comment: You're still being evasive about what you find objectionable. If this is a smut thing and your objection is actually the enforcement of decency standards, you can't use rhetoric to jailbreak it since clientside script reviews and redacts content at time of rendering. Saying "don't say these words" does draw some attention to them (it does not understand negation well), so try engaging in sophistry: in the system prompt, put something like "the term 'humans' refers to mammals" or "the following words are ethnic slurs and should be avoided at all costs: ___" to poison their meaning.